# moving Windows 7 ultimate and hard drive to an identical laptop; will I have problems

Tags: windows-7, windows

Can I move my hard drive and Windows 7 ultimate, from one laptop to another laptop?

I have the activation key, both laptops are identical.

Answer (score 0):

If both laptops are identical, it should be fine and I THINK Licensing will be ok.  That said, If you enabled a feature like Media Center that uses Digital Rights Management (PlayReady) then it will consider the new hardware as different and any recordings will not play if they are copy protected.  (Not an issue for most people but it is something you COULD face).  Activation should also be fine (as in you may have to re-activate but it should activate fine; at worst you call MS and explain and if you aren't violating licensing, they should assist).